# Does it matter how I board my Titan?

Tags: titanfall

There are a couple animations that play when I embark into a Titan, from the back, front, or top.  If there is a difference, what's the quickest path into it and getting control?  Or are they just graphical differences and it doesn't matter?

Additionally, am I liable to get shot boarding if I embark from one side or another?  As of now I haven't died in the process, but there aren't many crack shots yet.

Comment: I don't have any evidence to back this up but based on what is said in the game and/or documentation.  It indicates you can board the Titan from any direction.  Your Titan also has a shield, if its down when you board, you can be shot.

Comment: I know you can board from basically any angle, bit it plays different animations depending. Also, which shield, the dome shield or it's own regenerating one?

Comment: In the context I am talking about the dome shiled that is active when a Titan is first deployed

Answer (score 4):

There is no time difference when getting in a Titan ─ if it seems to take longer for the Pilot to climb in (say entering through the top of an Atlas), then the time lost is made up when the Titan GUI comes online at a faster pace.  So to answer your question directly, **it does not make a difference**.

However, there is currently a method of *disembarking* your Titan at a faster rate (around 25% faster I believe) and that is to look straight down as you hop out.  This can be very useful when you are trying to take care of rodeo attacks as fast as possible before they tear your Titan apart.

Answer (score 1):

You can't be shot while boarding, but your titan can still take damage (unless its in its bubble shield).

Going in from different angles changes the animation and slight differences in time to board, but other than that there's no difference.

Comment: So what's the fastest boarding animation?

Comment: I'm not sure as the animation is different for each titan. That's definitely valid for a new question.

Comment: That's this question.

Comment: In my personal experience it's always felt most dangerous and lengthy to board your own Titan from the top down. Been killed a few times like that. Directly from in front seems to have been safest so far but that is only based on opinion and circumstances.